# SSO on reverse-proxy?

Tags: single-sign-on, reverse-proxy

We're using AD and our (linux) websites needs SSO so the user is automatically signed in (the REMOTE_USER header is set).

Is this even possible with a reverse-proxy, and how?

I've tried for days now, and I can't pass the REMOTE_USER to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) on the Linux websites and ADFS on the AD side.